# How to restrict device join in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We are a team of remote workers trying to restrict access to 'corporate resources' to specific devices, which are virtual Desktop-as-a-Service machines hosted by a third party. Corporate resources are Office 365 applications, OneDrive and, eventually, services hosted on Azure. The right solution seems to be Azure AD Join. But I can't see how to limit Join to those VMs that are our 'corporate' workstations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure AD join needs users input your credentials of Azure AD Account. If you want to limit Azure AD join devices, you can limit users who can join their devices to AzureAD:

Go to Azure Portal > Azure Acitve Directory > Devices > Add memebers who can join devices to Azure AD.

[image]